# Can you determine USD swap rate movement probability from OTM swaption premiums?

Tags: probability, swaption, rates

E.g., the USD 1y x 4y swap rate is currently 2.84%.
ATM receiver swaption , European exercise is currently at ATM premium of 1.15% while swaption premium at strike 1.5% is 0.15% or about 90% lower than ATM premium. 
Can we infer that there is only a 10% chance that 4Y rates will be lower than 1.5% in 1 years time?
Is there any other way to use OTM Swaption premiums to determine rate movement probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for any European vanilla option you can infer the cumulative distribution function **under the pricing measure** by taking the derivative w.r.t. strike.

In the case of European swaptions the natural numeraire is the annuity $A(t)$, the pricing measure is the annuity probability measure $P^A$, and 
$$
\text{receiver swaption premium} = A(0) E^A[(K - S_T)^+]
$$
where $S_T$ is the swap rate on exercise, therefore
$$
P^A(S_T < K) = \frac{1}{A(0)} \frac{\partial \text{receiver swaption premium}}{\partial K}
$$

Comment: Dear Antoine, many thanks for your response. May I please request you to give me a worked out example using the numbers I have put and your formula. Apologies, I don’t have a quant background and have high maths handicap!!!